# Java game, restart on user command when game is over

Tags: java

In Java, I have a game and the way it runs is the following:

```
 public void start(){

    startGame();

 }
```

Now I want that every time the game is over, to rerun the game again after the user clicks on the screen of the game. I have objects in the game, and I would prefer not to remove them one by one, but if it is possible to remove all the created objects altogether and to rerun the game again. Is this possible and if yes, can anybody show me any way please?

Comment: Your objects ought to be in a GUI model class.  You would restart by clearing the values in the model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this button-based memory [game](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons), a `javax.swing.Timer` animates the opening screen. Pressing the <kbd>Start</kbd> button halts the timer and invokes `resetGame()`. When a game is won, the buttons are reset and the timer resumes.